# How can I get userID session after login in PHP?

Tags: php, database, function, session

```
<div class="w3-content w3-padding" style="max-width: 400px;">
    <h2 class="w3-center">LOGIN</h2>

    <form class="w3-container w3-card-4 w3-white w3-text-blue w3-margin" action="" method="POST">
        <div class="w3-row w3-section">
            <input class="w3-input w3-border w3-round-xxlarge w3-padding-large w3-xlarge" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
        </div>
        <div class="w3-row w3-section">
            <input class="w3-input w3-border w3-round-xxlarge w3-padding-large w3-xlarge" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <p class="w3-center">
            <button name="login" class="w3-btn w3-blue w3-round-xxlarge w3-padding-large w3-xlarge" style="width: 100%;">LOGIN</button>             
        </p>
        <hr>
        <h6 class="w3-text-black w3-center">Don't have an account? <a href="index.php?controller=user&&action=register" style="text-decoration: none;" class="w3-text-red">Register now</a></h6>    
    </form>
</div>
```

This is the page "login.php" in View. Next is the page "c_user.php" in Controller.

```
case 'login':{
        if(isset($_POST['login']))
        {
            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $password = md5($_POST['password']);
            if($db->login($username, $password)){
                $_SESSION['user_name'] = $username;

                //$_SESSION['user_id'] = $userID;

                if($_SESSION['user_type'] == 1){
                    header('location: index.php?controller=admin&action=adminhomepage');
                }else{
                    header('location: index.php?controller=view&action=homepage');
                }   
            } else{
                header('location: index.php?controller=user&action=login');
            }
        }
        require_once('View/login.php');
        break;
    }
```

The final page is "database.php" in Model:

```
public function login($username, $password){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE UserName='$username' AND Password='$password'";
        $this->execute($sql);
        return $this->getAllData(array($username,$password));
    }
```

I don't know how to get session of userID as well as userType after login successful to the website. I only get session of username. Help me!!

Comment: I hope you don't plan on taking this online; it's totally unsafe to use.

Comment: Yes I just have a basic knowledge of PHP and I am doing final project.

Comment: I just want to know how to get session of userID